# ApiController acess values textBox Windows Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I'm doing a project in Windows Forms with webapi. I would get a value of a textBox when the call is made from webapi.

Below is the code snippet, but it does not work as it gives the error after the code.

```
namespace TCCWindows
{
    public partial class FormPrincipal : Form
    {   
        public static string PegarCoordenadas()
        {
            return edtLatitudeGMS.Text + " | " + edtlngGMS.Text;
        }
    }

    public class GPSController : ApiController
    {

        public string Posicao()
        {
            return TCCWindows.FormPrincipal.PegarCoordenadas();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Error   2   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TCCWindows.FormPrincipal.edtLatitudeGMS' I:\C#\TCC\TCCWindows\FormPrincipal.cs   224 20  TCCWindows

Error   3   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TCCWindows.FormPrincipal.edtlngGMS'  I:\C#\TCC\TCCWindows\FormPrincipal.cs   224 50  TCCWindows
```

Comment: What are you expecting to have happen?  Where is the Form instantiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PegarCoordenadas method is static but Controls like edtLatitudeGMS belong to a certain instance of a form. Everything you reference in a static method needs to be static itself. So your code isn't valid.

When you made PegarCoordenadas static because you don't have a concrete reference to a FormPrincipal instance at the spot were you want to call it then you took the wrong direction to solve this. You **must** have concrete reference to such an instance. When you create FormPrincipal store the reference somewhere (maybe in your GPSController) and make it accessable in the Posicao method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
public partial class FormPrincipal : Form
{   
    public static string PegarCoordenadas()
    {
        return LatitudeGMS + " | " + LongGMS;
    }
    public static string LatitudeGMS, LongGMS;
    public FormPrincipal(){
         InitializeComponents();
         edtLatitudeGMS.TextChanged += (s,e) => { LatitudeGMS = edtLatitudeGMS.Text;};
         edtlngGMS.TextChanged += (s,e) => {LongGMS = edtlngGMS.Text;};
    }
}
```

You can use only `static stuff` in static methods.